# Populate Dataframe with other two Dataframes without generating multiple rows or column name suffixes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have this main dataframe that I wish to populate (blanks are NaNs):

`final_outcome` =

```
    bankId  latestPeriodEndDate tier1Ratio-mrq-0    tier1Ratio-mrq-1    leverageRatio-mrq-0 leverageRatio-mrq-1
0   1004381
```

The other two dataframes I wish to use to populate this one are:

`mrq_0`:

```
    bankId  tier1Ratio-mrq-0    leverageRatio-mrq-0
0   1004381 21.36   11.45
```

`mrq_1`:

```
    bankId  tier1Ratio-mrq-1    leverageRatio-mrq-1
0   1004381 15.82   8.65
```

What I have tried is like a cascade of merges like this:

```
final_outcome = final_outcome.merge(mrq_0, on = 'bankId').merge(mrq_1, on = 'bankId')
```

Or using this:

```
final_outcome.merge(mrq_0, on =['bankId', 'tier1Ratio-mrq-0', 'leverageRatio-mrq-0']).merge(mrq_1, on = ['bankId', 'tier1Ratio-mrq-1', 'leverageRatio-mrq-1'])
```

But unfortunately, the outcome adds additional columns with suffixes (for this one I'll paste a screenshot for better readability):

[image: Outcome from the cascade of merges]

Now, the outcome I desire is just a "more populated" version of final_outcome, ideally would look like something like this:

```
    bankId  latestPeriodEndDate tier1Ratio-mrq-0    tier1Ratio-mrq-1    leverageRatio-mrq-0 leverageRatio-mrq-1
0   1004381                                21.36               15.82                  11.45    8.65
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know if all the columns from final_outcome (assuming that is your first table to merge on) are always blank on the provided columns? If so I would simply drop those blank columns and then try a pd.merge()

Comment: Initially, it will. But afterwards, I will have to populate different rows. 

I'm thinking that perhaps pd.concat is better for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
d0 = {'bankId': {0: 1004381}, 'tier1Ratio-mrq-0': {0: 21.36}, 'leverageRatio-mrq-0': {0: 11.45}}
df0 = pd.DataFrame(d0)
d1 = {'bankId': {0: 1004381}, 'tier1Ratio-mrq-1': {0: 15.82}, 'leverageRatio-mrq-1': {0: 8.65}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

Doing:

```
final_outcome = df0.merge(df1)
final_outcome['latestPeriodEndDate'] = np.nan

print(final_outcome)
```

Output:

```
    bankId  tier1Ratio-mrq-0  leverageRatio-mrq-0  tier1Ratio-mrq-1  leverageRatio-mrq-1  latestPeriodEndDate
0  1004381             21.36                11.45             15.82                 8.65                  NaN
```